# Angular Hybrid Application, Upgraded Component with Template Function not receiving $element or $attrs

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-upgrade, angular-hybrid

As the title says, I am working in an Angular Hybrid app. I have an old AngularJS component that uses a `template` function to dynamically build itself based on the inputs passed in to it.

I've upgraded that component to be useable from Angular, however the `template` function for it no longer works because `$element` and `$attrs` aren't injected correctly in to the `template` function.

[Here's a simple stackblitz showing the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hybrid-upgrade-aq2wkx?file=ng1%2Fng1-demo.component.ts)

As you can see, when using the component directly from AngularJS, it is given the `$element` and `$attrs` values correctly, but when rendering it as an upgraded component from Angular, it doesn't. Is there some way I'm supposed to provide those manually for the upgraded component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is currently a limitation of upgraded component template functions. I opened a bug on Angular's github [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31565) and received that response. I've opened a PR [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/31637) to somewhat address the issue as best as possible.